# why I always get NaN when adding a new Field after triggering onCreate a new document in subcollection in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to add a new field in the user data (below name: "joko") by using `onCreate` cloud function for firestore triggered after creating  a new event in sub collection `createdEvents`

before adding a new document in `createdEvents` sub collection, the data will be like this:

(before)
[image]

I use this code to perform that action

```
export const updateEventsCreatedNumberWhenUserCreateNewEvent1 = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/createdEvents/{eventId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        const userID = context.params.userId
        const userRef = snap.ref.firestore.collection('users').doc(userID)
        const userSnapshot = await userRef.get()

        if (userSnapshot) {
            // if data is available

            const numberOfEventCreated = userSnapshot.data().numberOfEventCreated
            return userRef.update({
                numberOfEventCreated: numberOfEventCreated + 1
            })

        } else {

            const newUserData = userSnapshot.data()
            newUserData.numberOfEventCreated = 1
            return userRef.set(newUserData)

        }



    });
```

but I always get NaN in the numberOfEventCreated field that I just create. there is no error on firebase cloud function console log

(after)
[image]

what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially your document exists, so `if (userSnapshot)` is `true`. But it has no field `numberOfEventCreated`, so `userSnapshot.data().numberOfEventCreated` is `undefined`. And `undefined + 1` is `NaN` (for not-a-number).

You'll want to catch the condition differently:

```
if (userSnapshot) {
    // if data is available

    const numberOfEventCreated = userSnapshot.data().numberOfEventCreated
    return userRef.update({
        numberOfEventCreated: (numberOfEventCreated || 0) + 1
    })

} else {

    const newUserData = userSnapshot.data()
    newUserData.numberOfEventCreated = 1
    return userRef.set(newUserData)

}
```

The `(numberOfEventCreated || 0) + 1` evaluates to the actual value from the document, or (if there is no `numberOfEventCreated` in the document) to `0`.

Comment: does firestore store NaNs? Not seeing it under 'supported data types' but my queries are returning NaNs